# jqgrid:how to set edit option false for a particular column and update its vlaue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i have a jqgrid with inline editing working fine, my requirement is that i want to disable  the edit option for studentId, i declared editable:false for that studentId column, but when im clicking the save button im getting the error...'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'StudentId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method .....'

my jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var lastsel;

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/GetStudents/',
            datatype: 'json',

            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['StudentID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Actions', ],

            colModel: [
      { name: 'StudentID', sortable: false, key: true,editable:false },
      { name: 'FirstName', key: true },
      { name: 'LastName', sortable: false, key: true },
      { name: 'Email', width: 200, sortable: false, key: true },
      { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 75, sortable: false, editable: false}],
            cmTemplate: { align: 'center', editable: true },
            pager: '#pager',
            width: 750,
            rowNum: 15,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'StudentID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: ' My First JQgrid',
            gridview: true,
            width: 850,



            gridComplete: function () {
                var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');

                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    var cl = ids[i];

                    be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').editRow('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                    se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').saveRow('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                    ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\" />";
                    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be + se + ce });
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what information wait your server part. You can try to use

```
prmNames: {id: "StudentID"}
```

It will rename `id` parameter currently sent to the server to `StudentID`.

Comment: thnku, it worked perfectly but can u tell me what that line does, i m not able to understand the background process..now i want to editable:false to firstName column, when im saving, null value is being passed to the database, how to resolve this issue

Comment: @colorsbright: jqGrid send the `rowid` in the editing request in the form `id=123` where 123 is the `rowid`. So it uses `"id"` as the default *name* of the parameter `rowid`. Using `prmNames` you can *rename* any parameter which will be send to the server. In you use `prmNames: {id: "StudentID"}` then `id=123` will be changed in the POST request to `StudentID=123`. In the same way you can rename *any* of other parameters which will be send by jqGrid to the server.

Comment: okk, when i make FirstName column as not editable, how do i need to pass FirstName,..prmNames: {?: "FirstName"}

Comment: @colorsbright: First of all **YOU SHOULD REMOVE `key: true`** from other columns as `StudentID` (read my answer on your previous question). I could explain how to send `FirstName` but I see no sense on it. All needed information *is already on the server*. You need just use `StudentID`. I suppose that you have some problem *on the server part*. How you access to the database on the server side?

Comment: yes ur 100% right, sorry for my lameness...actually my issue was that null value was being passed and getting updated in my database for the column firstName, so i need to make changes in my procedure.....just with my curiosity i would like to ask, can v pass firstName value even after making it not editable

Comment: @colorsbright: I wrote you before that you probably don't need to send `firstName` to the server to be able to update it. Only the id (`StudentID`) is enough. You should post C# code of the corresponding action (see your `editurl`) and describe the problem. You should better to describe the problem in the new question.